# How to merge DataTables but combine rows if ID matches?

Tags: c#, datatable

**Input:**

Say I have two DataTables. The first one:

```
ID  Date    ValueA  ValueB
1   Nov.21  72.4    23.4
1   Nov.22  71.4    24.4
2   Nov.21  74.4    21.4
```

The second one:

```
ID  Date    ValueC  ValueD
1   Nov.21  42.4    53.4
1   Nov.22  41.4    54.4
2   Nov.21  44.4    51.4
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to do `DataTable1.Merge(DataTable2);`, but I get this:

```
ID  Date    ValueA  ValueB  ValueC  ValueD
1   Nov.21  72.4    23.4    
1   Nov.22  71.4    24.4    
2   Nov.21  74.4    21.4    
1   Nov.21                  42.4    53.4
1   Nov.22                  41.4    54.4
2   Nov.21                  44.4    51.4
```

**Desired result:**

I'd like to combine rows, if their ID and Date match.

I want this:

```
ID  Date    ValueA  ValueB  ValueC  ValueD
1   Nov.21  72.4    23.4    42.4    53.4
1   Nov.22  71.4    24.4    41.4    54.4
2   Nov.21  74.4    21.4    44.4    51.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to join the two DataTables based on `ID` and `Date` and then project/Load the results into a resultant DataTable using [`LoadDataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like:

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

var query = from row1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
            join row2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on
                new { ID = row1.Field<int>("ID"), Date = row1.Field<DateTime>("Date") }
                equals
                new { ID = row2.Field<int>("ID"), Date = row2.Field<DateTime>("Date") }
            select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        row1.Field<int>("ID"),
        row1.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
        row1.Field<double>("ValueA"),
        row1.Field<double>("ValueB"),
        row2.Field<double>("ValueC"),
        row2.Field<double>("ValueD")
    }, false);
```

Make sure that the types specified with [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method matches with that of your columns in `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks, have an upvote. But what if I have some variable number of tables, like 4 or 5? Do I have to do this multiple times, i.e. Join 1 onto 2, then Join the result onto 3, then Join the result onto 4, etc.?

Comment: @user1032613, in that case I would extract that to a method and pass my datatables current and next and get a `DataTable` back and merge those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to group by, then put the values back into a DataTable if you need it that way:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(s =>
                        new
                        {
                            ID = s.Field<int>("ID"),
                            Date = s.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                            ValueA = s.Field<int>("ValueA")
                        })
                    .GroupBy(
                        key => new { key.ID, key.Date },
                        (key, agg) =>
                        new
                        {
                            key.ID,
                            key.Date,
                            ValueA = agg.Max(a => a.ValueA) // etc.
                        });

        var grouped = new DataTable("grouped");

        foreach (var r in rows)
        {
            var row = grouped.NewRow();

            // Put the rows that are now as you want them back into a datatable

            grouped.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is missing a method to fill the datatable. it should be

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

var query = (from row1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
            join row2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on
                new { ID = row1.Field<int>("ID"), Date = row1.Field<DateTime>("Date") }
                equals
                new { ID = row2.Field<int>("ID"), Date = row2.Field<DateTime>("Date") }
            select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        row1.Field<int>("ID"),
        row1.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
        row1.Field<double>("ValueA"),
        row1.Field<double>("ValueB"),
        row2.Field<double>("ValueC"),
        row2.Field<double>("ValueD")
    }, false))
.CopyToDataTable();
```

the **.CopyToDataTable()**; is the magic keyword